# Swift syntax filter cannot be used

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have an empty array:

```
var indexPathArray: [[NSIndexPath]] = [[]]
```

And I have a tableView with multiple rows in multiple sections.
When a cell is pressed in UITableView, it adds NSIndexPath to the array like following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        indexPathArray[indexPath.section].append(indexPath)
    }
```

If a cell on the first row in section 1 is selected, previous method adds NSIndexPath to the first array in indexPathArray. The result will be like following:

```
[ [indexPath], [],[] ]
```

When I deselect the cell, I want to filter out what I selected. I implemented following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    indexPathArray = indexPathArray[indexPath.section].filter({ $0 != indexPath   })
}
```

In each array in indexPathArray, I'm basically trying to take out if same indexPath item is deselected. For example, if I double tap a cell twice, indexPath item will be added and will be removed by filter function.

However, it throws me an error on filter function saying:

```
Cannot invoke 'filter' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (NSIndexPath) throws -> Bool)'
expected an argument list of type (@noescape (Self.Generator.Element) throws -> Bool)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why don't you use `-indexPathsForSelectedRows`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating `indexPathArray` with the filtered array of one section. The compiler is confused, because you're updating an `[[NSIndexPath]]` variable with `filter` that will result in `[NSIndexPath]`.

Instead of:

```
indexPathArray = indexPathArray[indexPath.section].filter { $0 != indexPath }
```

You should instead update that particular section, e.g.:

```
indexPathArray[indexPath.section] = indexPathArray[indexPath.section].filter { $0 != indexPath }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Rob

Answer (score 2):

The post by *Rob* does answer your question.

Please also consider that if you just need to keep track of the selected indexes then using a `Set` is much easier then the `array of array of IndexPath` you are using.

```
var set = Set<NSIndexPath>()
```

### Adding an IndexPath

```
set.insert(indexPath)
```

### Checking if an IndexPath is in the Set

```
set.contains(indexPath)
```

### Removing an IndexPath

```
set.remove(indexPath)
```